# I was wondering if there is a way to use Adobe Illustrator's curvature tool as a script

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, adobe-scriptui

I have to connect pathpoints with a natural curve with script.

I know that it is possible using the curvature tool, but I couldn't find a way to use it in a script.

Is there any way to use curvature tool in a script?

I know how to create curves using anchors and left,rightdirections, but I felt it was impossible to calculate a function to create natural curves like the curvature tool.

I expect to be able to create natural curves like using the curvature tool in the script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to draw natural curve like curvature tool in adobe illustrator by scripting.

Comment: That is the task you want to accomplish. Can you show us the code you have so far and explain in detail what the problem with it is?